# How to extract specific information from a file in python

Tags: python, file

I have a file with following format:

```
device={
   id=1
   tag=10
   name=device1
}
device={
   id=2
   tag=20
   name=device2
}
device={
   id=3
   tag=30
   name=device3
}
```

So let's say I am only interested in device with `id=2` and I want to extract its tag number(this is configurable and will be changed from some other code). So I need to extract tag number of the device id 2. How can I do this in python. I have done following:

```
ID='id=2'

with open("file.txt") as file:
          for line in file:
              if line.strip() ==  ID:
                  #Here I do not know what to write 
                  # to extract 20
```

Thanks

Comment: Parse the whole file into a dict of dicts, with the ids as top-level keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the next line using `line.readline()` try to use this code:

```
ID='id=2'

with open("file.txt") as file:
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if line.strip() == ID:
            nextline = file.readline()
            result = nextline.strip().split('=')[1]
       if line == '':
            break
```

Comment: Why you are using `file.readline()` and what does this line means `result = nextline.strip().split('=')[1]` What exactly `[1]` do in this.? Also when you are doing `if line.strip() == '':` Dont you think it will break early because it may find blank space

Comment: `nextline.strip().split('=')[1]` this is mean that we split our string by '=' and this is return list, so we get second item of this list. About end of file i edit my code, becouse strip is not needed. If we get the end of file '' is returned, but if we get blank line '\n' is returned

Comment: Thanks. But when I tried it, it says `TypeError: descriptor 'readline' of 'file' object needs an argument`

Comment: Look at your code, maybe you do some mistake when copy, because this code works fine when i run it

Comment: Yes it was because of my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

With [***re.search***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) function:

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    id_num = 'id=2'
    tag_num = re.search(r'' + id_num + '\s+tag=([0-9]+)', f.read())
    print(tag_num.group(1))
```

The output:

```
20
```

---

- `f.read()` - reads the file contents (as text)
- `r'' + id_num + '\s+tag=([0-9]+)'` - constructing regex pattern, so it would become `id=2\s+tag=([0-9]+)` where `\s` is one or many whitespace characters(including newlines) and `([0-9]+)` is the 1st captured group containing ***tag*** number
- `tag_num.group(1)` - extracting the value of the 1st captured/parenthesized group `1` from the [*match*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) object `tag_num`

Comment: Thankyou. Its a bit high level for me. It would be great if you add comment, specially on 5th line. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("") as file:
    #print file.read()

    for line in file:
        #print line.split()
        if line.strip()==ID:
          d=file.next()              #reads next line
          print d.split('=')[1]
          break
```